# PHP Classes load() method good/bad practice?

Tags: php, oop

Just wondering if you could shed some light on best practices?

Would having a load method in a Class be the correct/best way?

```
Class Test extends Foo{

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function load($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Or would it be concidered better practice to just have the load method logic in the constructor?

```
Class Test extends Foo{

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

The 2nd option seems to be more logical to me as it's one less method and it's called automatically etc, however, I've seen the 1st option more often. Is there a reason for this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is closely related to lazy loading - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: The fact that you're asking this question indicates that your `Foo` class has some work done in the constructor, which is bad practice. If you can help it, change `Foo` so that all work is done on a different *public* method, called from one level above, and not from the constructor. If you cannot, the second is a better option in my eyes, assuming `id` and `name` are both needed for the object to function.

Comment: @SamDufel: I don't see the similarities?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - The general idea behind lazy loading is to instantiate an object without having all of its data / resources initialized; you wait to initialize ("load") them until they're actually needed.

Comment: @SamDufel: Not really, you can't, by definition *instantiate an object without having all of it's dependencies*. You do wait until you do have all of these dependencies, usually via a callback or some other form of cache, before instantiating the actual object. The object itself never gets instantiated until you have all of the dependencies.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I understand what you're saying as in some situations I would agree, but in some cases Foo could just be a basic CRUD class. I didn't really put that in for any real reason other than a 'why not'. The question was mainly about whether a it's a bad thing just to have the constructor do the loading. Thank you, though.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - What are you quoting?  I didn't say anything about dependencies.

Comment: You generally want to be doing as little as possible in your contrustor, assuming you even need one at all, it should only be used to initialize the object to a sensible default state.  All actual work should happen in other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is best. A constructor is meant to **prepare the object for use**. It is the perfect place to initialize properties etc. Unless you have a good reason for using load() instead of the constructor, go with the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The first option uses slightly more abstraction, I suppose.

I can see a situation where you might need to copy the code and separating the variable assignments into a `load()` or `init()` function might make your code a litter easier to update for the new purpose.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage of the 1st option is that you don't require the developer to supply the information straight away. Although it is more error prone since one might forget about calling the load function. If all other functions require $id and $name to be set it's best to require the arguments when creating a new object.

On the other hand not having the load function prevents you from reloading the object with new values later on in the code.

You can combine the two by calling the load function from the constructor:

```
Class Test extends Foo{

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct( $id, $name )
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load( $id, $name );
    }

    public function load($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

OR if you don't require the values to be set on creation you can use PHPs funky function overloading stuff:

```
Class Test extends Foo{

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if( func_num_args() === 2 ){
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'load'), func_get_args() );
        }
    }

    public function load($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I -1ed just because of the magic. Really? Reading the public API for your class, would you be able to guess that you can pass items to the constructor?

Comment: I guess if you were writing a public API one would add PHPdoc or another sort of documentation explaining that there are optional parameters for the constructor. Making it clear for future developers.

Also it was just an alternative to the first example which I would prefer.

Comment: Common misconception. Your code should be as self-descriptive as possible. You have just successfully introduced *magic*. Magic is evil. Don't introduce magic. You either **need them at generation, or you don't**. Don't try to eat your cake and have it too :)

Answer (score -2):

You could extend load() per particular member.

Making each property protected or private and providing a set/get function for one of them.
That's an acceptable way and sometimes is better than overloading your constructor with dependencies and logic.

Try this and see if it helps you:

```
    Class Test extends Foo{

    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

It's called getters and setters and it's a more clean and robust approach.

Besides, as mentioned in other answers - It provides better re-usability, ability to have your object clean of data with null values, but that's all dependent on what is the intent of your class!